# Mocking an activity Android unit testing with MVP

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mvp, dagger-2

We're setting up a new native Android project with a strong focus on TDD and wish to use the MVP architectural pattern to better seperate our code. With the release of Dagger 2 we're going to use that for dependancy injection.

We can implement simple unit tests, testing the basic logic of the presenters but when we try to mock the activity (which is our view) the unit tests break. We think this is due to the presenter itself being injected into the activity, we're injecting the presenter to manage the activity using field injection.

So my real question would be what is the best way to mock an activity in MVP?

Comment: Have you tried to let android studio 1.x create an app for you which includes junit-3 tests? The generated test code contains an activity test. How does your test code differ from these generated tests? Can you provide us "breaking"-sample-code. whithout these it is quite likely that this question will be closed as beeing to broad.

Comment: @k3b thanks for getting back, I'm aware we're likely to get closed but I thought it would be better to ask!